# How can I get a reference of a table index?(lua)

Tags: lua, coronasdk, love2d, luajit, entity-component-system

I want to get a reference to something in a table, but when i try:

```
myReferences[x] = table[i]
```

I copy the value.
I tried using a variable between the tables:

```
local myReference = table[i]
myReferences[x] = myReference
```

but that does not work either

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What are you really trying to do?

Comment: This problem should not be possible, since Lua is strictly pass-by-reference (at least semantically, not under the hood). Also, if the value is a nil, boolean, number, or string, then it's immutable, so copy vs reference would make no difference anyway. If Vlad guessed correctly that you're trying to get a C++-style reference, then Lua just doesn't have that feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "reference" thing in Lua. When you assign something - that only binds new value to a variable or to a table's element.

If you need a reference to a table's element, you need the table itself and the value of referencing index stored together. That pair will be your equivalent for a reference. For convenience it may be wrapped in some kind of a functional object, but essentially it would be the same pair.

But as noted in comments, it's likely that you're trying to solve some other task in a c++-ish way, so you'd better explain what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: `There is no "reference" thing in Lua`.  Actually, there is a "reference" thing in Lua.  It is usually referred to as "upvalue" :-)  Upvalue is a reference to heap-based variable.  Unfortunately, reference to some inner element (such as value inside a table) indeed does not exist in Lua.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, Right, the upvalue is referencing the other variable. Thx for correcting :)